# Fantasy manga/comic that had some themes of the Garden of Eden

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, manga

I don't remember the character's looks too well, but I know the story. This was probably a web comic and I read this a really long time ago.

The main character was a little girl starting off in a blank space, she can hear a voice (kinda like God I guess) and it taught her to bring clay creations to life. Shaping clay and blow breathe life into it.

She creates a field of grass and flowers and then a rose (which became important later on). Then she wanted a friend and created something like her but a speck of clay fell on it and it became a boy (..yeah anyways).

Creating animals that ended up fighting. She and the boy created land, trees, and fruits. The trees were starting to lose shape and for a while there was just a vast ocean and an island was formed (this part is a little foggy).